# Redis Timeout performing SETEX

Tags: c#, redis

I am using StackExchange.Redis 1.2.6 on my client server to connect with redis server version 3.0.504 installed on a windows server. I face the below timeout exception in my client server causing inconsistency of the application.

**My observations:**

1. There is no much CPU or Memory usage at the time of exception in my
   client server.
2. I looked into the slowlog and I was not able to find
       any command at that time.

Below is my configuration and I maintain a single connection to redis throughout my application.

```
private static ConfigurationOptions GetRedisClusterConfiguration() {
    ConfigurationOptions configuration = null;
    try {
        RedisConfigSection config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(RedisConfigSection.SECTION_NAME) as RedisConfigSection;
        configuration = new ConfigurationOptions();
        configuration.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
        configuration.ConnectTimeout = 15000;
        configuration.ConfigCheckSeconds = 60;
        configuration.AllowAdmin = true;
        configuration.ConnectRetry = 5;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.Servers.Password)) configuration.Password = config.Servers.Password;

        foreach(var server in config.Servers) {
            configuration.EndPoints.Add($ "{server.Host}:{server.Port}");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        log.Error(ex);
    }
    return configuration;
}

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Instance {
    get {
        if (instance == null) {
            lock(safetyLock) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    try {
                        ConfigurationOptions configuration = GetRedisClusterConfiguration();
                        StringWriter loginfo = new StringWriter();
                        instance = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration, loginfo);
                        if (instance != null && !instance.IsConnected) log.Info(loginfo.ToString());
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        log.Error(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing SETEX
>   vuprodgenericgenevaservice_executormsg_geneva prod parallel, inst: 1,
>   mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 3, qu: 0, qs: 3, qc: 0, wr: 0,
>   wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: xxxx, serverEndpoint:
>   Unspecified/xxxx:6379, keyHashSlot: 3134, IOCP:
>   (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=78,Free=1969,Min=8,Max=2047) (Please take a look at this article
>   for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
>   http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
configuration.SyncTimeout = 15000;
```